# How do I make any file extension be recognized as HTML-"compliant" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed Web Tools Platform(3.6.2) and it now automatically closes any HTML tags I use.

```
e.g. typing <div> will automatically insert </div>
```

But it only works for files using .html extension. How can I extending this feature to other file extensions?

I've associated the extention to the HTML and web page editor via this [guide (click here)](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml) but still doesn't work. I've also searched the net but nothing useful came up.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have already edited the file before doing the association it will still open with the original editor.

Right click on the file and select 'Open With > HTML editor' to open with the HTML editor. You should only have to do this once.

Comment: still doesn't work. I've restarted eclipse/rebooted my mac/right click on the file and select open with HTML editor. Thanks for the suggestion though.